# Emptying the <tbody> is not working

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, html-table

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSearch').bind('click', function () {
                var textS = $("#txtSearch").val();
                var filterS = $("#Filter option:selected").val();
                var url = '@Url.Action("SearchGuest","Dashboard")';
                alert(url);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url,
                    data:{text:textS,filter:filterS},
                    success: function (emp) {
                        $('#TableGuest tbody > tr').remove();
                        jQuery.each(emp, function (i, val) {

                            $('#TableGuest tr:last').after("<tr><td>"+val.Name+"</td><td>"+val.FatherName+"</td><td>"+val.CNIC+"</td><td>"+val.Phone+"</td></tr>");
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (emp) {

                    }
                });


            });
        });
```

I have tried various function like

- `$('#TableGuestBody').empty()`
- `$('#TableGuest tbody > tr').remove();`
- `$("#TableGuestBody").html("");`

But none of the above are working :(

Its keeps on adding new rows on without deleting previous rows!

Note: I want only to remove the `<tr>` inside `<tbody>`

Comment: Are you sure your table has a `<tbody>` element?

Comment: Yes ofc it has  `<tbody id="TableGuestBody">`

Comment: Your use of `$('#TableGuest tr:last')` suggests maybe not? - because that would only be adding after the last `<tr>` element, and if the `<tbody>` element was empty, would mean that the new rows would be added to the `<thead>` section. I suspect its the adding of the new rows which is the problem. Try using `$('#TableGuestBody').append(yourNewRow);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you do have a `<tbody id="TableGuestBody">` element, then using `$('#TableGuestBody').empty()` will work fine (and clear all `<tr>` elements).

Your issue is with the way you are adding new rows.

```
$('#TableGuest tr:last').after(...);
```

will add new rows after the last `<tr>` element in the table, and since you have just removed all rows in the `<tbody>` element, the new rows are being added to your `<thead>` element. So now when you call `$('#TableGuestBody').empty()` its clearing the contents of an already empty `<tbody>` element, but you still see the previously added rows because they are in the `<thead>` element. Modify your code for adding the new rows to

```
$('#TableGuestBody').append(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work for you it works for me

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("tbody").find("tr").remove();
    });
```

with this it will only delete the `tr` inside the `tbody`

### OR

You can be more specific which tbody you want to empty in case you have multiple tables on your page

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("tbody#TableGuestBody").find("tr").remove();
    });
```

check it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/meeneshjain/jdakzojx/)**

Comment: Same issue! i doesn't delete previous rows and keeps on adding more :S

Comment: did you see the example i gave you